# How do I craft a Core Data query of objects without an item in relationship?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Say I have a Core Data entity called "Bucket". A Bucket has a name and a many-to-one relationship, named "items", to an entity named "Item", which have an attribute, "url". Business rule requires that an item with a given URL can be in a bucket only once. (Aside: Man I would love proper constraints in Core Data!) Here's my question: How can I fetch Buckets that do *not* contain an Item with a given URL?

IOW, how might I do the equivalent of this SQL in core data?

```
SELECT name FROM buckets
 WHERE bucket_id NOT IN (
    SELECT bucket_id FROM items WHERE url = ?
);
```

Is that possible using predicates for core data fetch requests?

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I get this right:

You have

- `Bucket` with a `name` property
- `Item` with a `url` property

and a relationship like this

`Bucket` <--->> `Item`

i.e. a bucket can have multiple items, but each item is only in one bucket.

Now, what you need is a **Subquery Expression**:

```
(SUBQUERY(items, $x, $x.url == %@).@count == 0)
```

i.e.

```
NSString *urlAsString; // Assume we have this
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(items, $x, $x.url == %@).@count == 0)", urlAsString];
```

And you'll want an index on `url` for `Item` for performance reasons.

Comment: Er, in practice I have a one-to-many relationship, so I don't think the inverse will work. Will update the question.